# ceiling light where stud is

Tags: electrical, studs

I want to put three pendant lights where there is no light currently. I drilled a test hole with a drill bit and hit wood. I'm trying to move it elsewhere, but if not can I do something with a pancake junction box attached to the stud and cut only the drywall out? Any other ideas short of moving the light?

Comment: How many cables are running into this box?

Comment: There is no box, just a wire going to track lighting about 8 inches off center of dining room table. I want to remove track lighting, then put in three pendents centered on table. So, a 12/2 going into first box, then connected to each in line.

Comment: This plan will violate box fill requirements in all boxes. The most you can have in a 6 inch pancake box is 2 14 gauge and one grounding wire with no internal clamp and no strap.

Comment: @bib -- yeah, a saddle box would be a far better bet for the querent's requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use a saddle mount ceiling box with at least 11.25in3 of space for this application as pancake boxes don't have enough room for 2 incoming 12/2 W/G cables -- they don't even have 10in3 of space, typically.  (Image below is simply representative.)

[image: an exemplar saddle mount box]

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that existed. Now if I could just find it in stock somewhere local....